# multiples kwargs en template de django

Tags: django, url

Tengo definida una expresión regular para capturar parámetros opcionales en una vista.

```
 url(r'^lista/((?P<tematica>[0-9]+)/(?P<pageIndex>[0-9]+)/(?P<pageSize>[0-9]+))|/$', views.PinturasListView.as_view(), name='lista')
```

en teoría tematica, pageIndex y pageSize son opcionales (los 3 parámetros o ninguno deberìan de llegar a la vista). El problema que cuando trato de poner los argumentos opcionales desde el template me marca error en la siguiente linea:

```
<a href="{% url 'pintura:lista' tematica='1' pageIndex='0' pageSize='6' %}">
```

en cambio si lo uso así funciona:

```
<a href="{% url 'pintura:lista' %}">
```

pero necesito pasarle los kwargs para que haga lo que necesito.
Especificamente la descripciòn del error es:

```
Reverse for 'lista' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'tematica': u'1', u'pageIndex': u'0', u'pageSize': u'6'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'pinturas/lista/((?P<tematica>[0-9]+)/(?P<pageIndex>[0-9]+)/(?P<pageSize>[0-9]+))|/$']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno, yo te recomendaría primero cambiar el final de tu url por algo así:

```
r'^lista/((?P<tematica>[0-9]+)/(?P<pageIndex>[0-9]+)/(?P<pageSize>[0-9]+)/)?$'
```

Lo que hice fue cambiar el `|` (pipe) por un `?`, así es mas entendible, luego, para solucionar el error, hay que hacer lo siguiente, partiendo que estas encerrando en un paréntesis para agrupar, django, el primer grupo en capturar será el paréntesis en general, por lo cual no podrá resolver nada, entonces para evitar que capture ese paréntesis, se le agrega un `?:` para que omita el grupo, quedando así tu url:

```
r'^lista/(?:(?P<tematica>[0-9]+)/(?P<pageIndex>[0-9]+)/(?P<pageSize>[0-9]+)/)?$'
```

Así ya te aseguras que haga el match sobre lo que está dentro del grupo, y no del grupo.

Cualquier duda, comenta.